# What are the css classess for changing default Red dropdown color kendo react

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

What are the css selectors for version 5.11.0 dropdown?

What is the recommended way in which file we should change it

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selectors for a Kendo React dropdown in version 5.11.0 would basically depend upon the specific style and structure of the dropdown component that you are using. However, you can do one thing, inspect the HTML structure of your dropdown component using your browser's developer tools to identify the relevant selectors that you need to target with your custom CSS styles.

The recommended way to change the styles of a Kendo React dropdown is to create a separate CSS file for your custom styles and import it into your project after the Kendo React stylesheet. This way, your custom styles will take precedence over the default styles of Kendo React.

Below example you can refer for how to import your custom stylesheet into your React project:

```
import React from 'react';
import './custom-styles.css';
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';

// Your component code

export default MyComponent;
```

In the above example, the custom stylesheet custom-styles.css is imported first, followed by the default Kendo React stylesheet @progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css. This way, your custom styles will take precedence over the default styles of Kendo React.